# A resource for cartoon bodies (and other 'clip art')

Tags: images

I have cropped out the face of my friend and, for his birthday, I want to stick his face onto different bodies. Is there a website or some other resource to get clip art or templates of bodies of different characters to paste the head on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Body Switcher](http://www.bodyswitcher.com/) lets you upload a photo and put it on multiple different bodies. You can also take shots directly from a webcam.